# How can I categorize variables, count variables and define their percentages in Rstudio

Tags: r, count, rstudio, percentage, categorization

[Data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4IoV.png)This is my first time working in R studio.
I have a database of 36 participants but it has 150600 entries.
There is a column for the participants:
A column for the probes   Activityprobe/ Screenprobe, SMSprobe and CallLogprobe
A column for the Activity Level  High/low/none,  screenon/off etc.

I need a code that helps me count the activity level of all the participants
High activity level. No activity level and Low activity level. 
And to help me find out for every Participant what the percentages are of all their high/no/low activity.

For screenprobe I need to count how many times the participant turned their screen on and how many times they turned it off and the percentage of screen on/off.

For callLog I need to count how many times each participant got called and the percentage.

For SMS I need to count the number of SMS for each participant and their percentage.

I also need to categorize the probes. So that my database shows all the activity levels first, organized by none/high/low and then all the screenprobes, organized by on and off etc.

I hope that my description is clear

Comment: If you could provide som example data it would easier to tailor an answer to you that would work directly

Comment: So I am not familiar with R language, but until now. I made factors of the screenProbe and ActivityProbe >str(edu.mit.media.funf.probe.builtin.ScreenProbe_factor) Factor w/ 3 levels "none","screenoff",..: 1 3 2 and I changed the values to                          
numeric >                                                                                         
Screenusage <-as.numeric(edu.mit.media.funf.probe.builtin.ScreenProbe_factor) > Screenusage [1] 1 3 2. I did the same thing for ActivityProbe

Comment: I also made a new database with the 4 columns I need > Essentials <- c("Participants","Probetype","Valuepecified","Valuedetailed")
> newdata <-gmoji_passive_data_1_[Essentials]
> View(newdata) and I used melt to get the probetypes organized > md <- melt(newdata, id=(c("Participants", "Probetype","Valuepecified", "Valuedetailed")))
> View(md)

Comment: How can I share data on this page?                                         My database shows me the participant ID - the Activityprobe- the activitylevel - none/high/low. For screenprobe it shows the participant ID - the screeprobe- sceen on/off - false/true. So I need to figure out how to count the 3 types of activlevel, the 2 types of screenprobe and the frequency of calls and sms per participant. I think this is the last step? I have been doing all of this with youtube tutorials and examples on google

Comment: I added an image!